# Why does the stm32f103 serial port in freertos not enter the interrupt when I use it to interrupt receiving data?

Tags: stm32f1

I had no problem using the serial port interrupt to receive data in bare metal, but when I ported this code to freertos, The interrupt channel is changed from USART1_IRQn to USART1_IRQChannel (because USART1_IRQn is not defined in stm32f10x_lib.h in freertos), nothing else has changed, but it is an interrupt that does not enter serial port 1

I checked the connection, whether I forgot the serial port initialization and whether I turned on or off the serial port interrupt, but no problem was found. But when I port this code to freertos, the interrupt channel selection is changed from USART1_IRQn to USART1_IRQChannel (because USART1_IRQn is not defined in stm32f10x_lib.h in freertos), and nothing else is changed. But it just doesn't go into the interrupt of serial port 1

Comment: I have cut out some copy+paste duplication from this question (and there is still some left) but I am not sure the remaining question produces a reproducible problem. How could a reader replicate what you are seeing?

Comment: Is the vector table correct? Does it contain the correct handler address for USART1?